# How to associate a section with its headerLabel in a UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Every section in my `UITableView` has a `headerLabel.text` value, and what I want is for it to use this value as a parameter in the `deleteFromMatchCenter` function thats run inside of the `deleteButtonPressed` IBAction.

I've attempted to do that as you can see in my code, but as expected, the app won't compile because `headerLabel.text` isn't a public property. How can I make it so that the delete button on a section uses its specific headerLabel as the parameter?

```
MatchCenterViewController.h:

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import "AsyncImageView.h"
#import "SearchViewController.h"

@interface MatchCenterViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource>

@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet NSString *itemSearch;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *imageURLs;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *matchingCategoryCondition;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *matchingCategoryLocation;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *matchingCategoryMaxPrice;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *matchingCategoryMinPrice;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *matchCenterArray;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *searchTerm;

@end
```

MatchCenterViewController.m:

```
#import "MatchCenterViewController.h"
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MatchCenterViewController () <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITableView *matchCenter;
@end

@implementation MatchCenterViewController


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.matchCenter = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds style:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle];
    self.matchCenter.frame = CGRectMake(0,50,320,self.view.frame.size.height-100);
    _matchCenter.dataSource = self;
    _matchCenter.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:self.matchCenter];

    _matchCenterArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.matchCenterArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];

    [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"MatchCenter"
                       withParameters:@{
                                        @"test": @"Hi",
                                        }
                                block:^(NSArray *result, NSError *error) {

                                    if (!error) {
                                        _matchCenterArray = result;
                                        [_matchCenter reloadData];

                                        NSLog(@"Result: '%@'", result);
                                    }
                                }];
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return _matchCenterArray.count;
}

//the part where i setup sections and the deleting of said sections

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 21.0f;
}


- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 21)];
    headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

    _searchTerm = [[[[_matchCenterArray  objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:@"Top 3"] objectAtIndex:3]objectForKey:@"Search Term"];

    UILabel *headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 0, 250, 21)];
    headerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", _searchTerm];
    headerLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]];
    headerLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    headerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    [headerView addSubview:headerLabel];

    UIButton *deleteButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    deleteButton.tag = section + 1000;
    deleteButton.frame = CGRectMake(300, 2, 17, 17);
    [deleteButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"xbutton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [deleteButton addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [headerView addSubview:deleteButton];
    return headerView;
}



- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
     return 3;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Initialize cell
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        // if no cell could be dequeued create a new one
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // No cell seperators = clean design
    tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    // title of the item
    cell.textLabel.text = _matchCenterArray[indexPath.section][@"Top 3"][indexPath.row][@"Title"];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];

    // price of the item
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%@", _matchCenterArray[indexPath.section][@"Top 3"][indexPath.row][@"Price"]];
    cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0f green:127/255.0f blue:31/255.0f alpha:1.0f];

    // image of the item
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:_matchCenterArray[indexPath.section][@"Top 3"][indexPath.row][@"Image URL"]]];
    [[cell imageView] setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]];
    //[cell imageView].frame = CGRectMake(45.0,10.0,10,10);

    return cell;

}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 65;
}


- (IBAction)deleteButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {

    [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"deleteFromMatchCenter"
                       withParameters:@{
                                        @"searchTerm": headerLabel.text,
                                        }
                                block:^(NSDictionary *result, NSError *error) {

                                    if (!error) {
                                        NSLog(@"Result: '%@'", result);
                                        [_matchCenter reloadData];
                                    }
                                }];
}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

@end
```

Comment: Isn't this crazy mess what you are using to get the text? `[[[[_matchCenterArray  objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:@"Top 3"] objectAtIndex:3]objectForKey:@"Search Term"];`

Answer (score 0):

You're using the tag property of the button to store the section it belongs to. So messy.

```
- (NSString *)textForSection:(NSInteger)section {
    [[[[_matchCenterArray  objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:@"Top 3"] objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:@"Search Term"];
}

- (IBAction)deleteButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSString *sectionText = [self textForSection:(sender.tag - 1000)];
    [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"deleteFromMatchCenter"
                       withParameters:@{
                                        @"searchTerm": sectionText,
                                        }
                                block:^(NSDictionary *result, NSError *error) {

                                    if (!error) {
                                        NSLog(@"Result: '%@'", result);
                                        [_matchCenter reloadData];
                                    }
                                }];
}
```

I think you should change your `deleteButtonPressed` method to take a section.

## viewForHeaderInSection

```
UIButton *deleteButton = [UIButton buttonWithAction:^{
    [self deleteButtonPressedForSection:section];
}];
```

## Delete Method

```
- (void)deleteButtonPressedForSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSString *sectionText = [self textForSection:section];
}
```

## UIButton Category

```
+ (instancetype)buttonWithAction:(CompletionBlock)action {
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button addTarget:action action:@selector(invoke) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setAssociatedObject:action forSelector:_cmd]; //you're going to have to write this method yourself
    return button;
}
```

Comment: That exception is saying that `MatchCenterViewController` doesn't implement the method `deleteButtonPressed:`.

Comment: Don't forget that you can't use use `addTarget:action:` to perform a selector that takes an argument other than the sender. This category method lets you get around that using blocks!

Comment: Can you explain what's going on here?: `[button setAssociatedObject:action forSelector:_cmd]`